# Is SurfaceView always needed when taking picture?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I've developed an app that takes pictures at certain time intervals. It works fine with android 2.3 but it crashes on an android 4.1 device. I do not use any SurfaceView for preview the picture on the screen. I've read a post that states that "most of the modern Android devices now check that a SurfaceView exists and has a non-zero width and height".

Might be this the case for which my camera.takePicture(...) crashes on new devices? If so, what is the best way to solve this problem considering that my app runs when the screen is off and therefore does not make sense showing the preview of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SurfaceTexture on 4.0 and higher. But there is no guarantee that your app will work on a non-rooted device, because the purpose of required active preview is to improve end-user's privacy and security.